# Как в Delphi в обработчике `OnMouseMove` определить источник события относительный или абсолютный (мышь или планшет)?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, мышь, vcl

У моего ПК есть 2 устройства ввода с которыми я работаю попеременно - мышь и графический планшет (Wacom). Мышь, как известно, генерирует относительные координаты (типа `X +5` `Y +1`), а планшет - абсолютные (типа `X 567` `Y 876`). Windows их берет и перед отдачей в приложение преобразует в абсолютные.

Как мне в обработчике события `OnMouseMove` определить от какого из устройств пришло событие и, соответственно, были ли порождены новые координаты относительным или абсолютным устройством ввода? А в идеале - увидеть "сырое" событие от устройства ввода.

Видел что есть флаги `ssTouch` `ssPen` в `TShiftState` добавляемые `MouseOriginToShiftState` (которая внутри вызывает `GetMessageExtraInfo` [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/tablet/system-events-and-mouse-messages?redirectedfrom=MSDN)), но похоже, что они относятся к планшетным ПК, а не к отдельным планшетам как устройству ввода.

Также слышал что есть `RAWMOUSE structure (winuser.h)` и `MOUSE_MOVE_RELATIVE` / `MOUSE_MOVE_ABSOLUTE` ([MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawmouse?redirectedfrom=MSDN)), но как им пользоваться пока не понятно.

Comment: Вот интересное есть: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/tablet/system-events-and-mouse-messages?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @MBo `MouseOriginToShiftState` это как раз обертка над этим, и она к сожалению не работает. Добавлю это уточнение в вопрос.

Comment: Лет 10 назад у меня был планшет Wacom и я писал для него достаточно простые программы на Delphi. Но к нему шла обёртка для фирменной DLL. Сейчас такого нет?

Comment: "обёртка для фирменной DLL"? У меня дрова стоят, все отлично работает, дело только в обработке курсора когда надо его "захватить" (делаю 3д редактор, где надо зажать ЛКМ и крутить модель, программно "держа" курсор на месте). Нашел почти рабочий код, на днях напишу сюда ответ )

Comment: Так, по идее, должно и быть. Но у меня есть примеры, когда не так: к устройству установлены драйверы, можно получать данные, но если работать через API, всё гораздо лучше: к примеру, у нас есть хроматограф ТСХ, который система видит, как сканер. С него можно получать картинки. Но, если использовать штатную DLL (сами писали обёртку для Delphi), можно вытаскивать гораздо больше. То же самое с принтером печати этикеток на пробирках.

Comment: @user7860670 работаю с планшетом вместо мыши более 15 лет. Дело в том, что Windows (и дрова планшета, заточенные под это) достаточно хорошо абстрагирует и унифицирует все устройства ввода сама. Мыши, трекболы, планшеты, тачи, итп. VCL обобщает это еще больше. В 99,5% случаев, все работает "из коробки". И только в последнем 0,5% случаев вдруг есть различия. Городить ради этого свою систему обработки ввода - представляется весьма избыточным. Большинство же этих 0,5% проблем решаются как раз учетом флага relative/absolute (иногда выносят отдельной галкой, но мне нужен именно автодетект).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Зарегистрировать слушателя "сырых" событий (иначе они не приходят) и подписаться на получение событий:

   ```
   procedure RegisterListener;
   const
     // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/hid-usages#usage-page
     HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC = 1;
     HID_USAGE_PAGE_GAME = 5;
     HID_USAGE_PAGE_LED = 8;
     HID_USAGE_PAGE_BUTTON = 9;
     // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/hid-usages#usage-id
     HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE = 2;
     HID_USAGE_GENERIC_KEYBOARD = 6;
   var
     rid: tagRAWINPUTDEVICE;
   begin
     // To receive WM_INPUT messages, an application must first register the raw input devices using RegisterRawInputDevices.
     // By default, an application does not receive raw input.
     rid.usUsagePage := HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC;
     rid.usUsage := HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE;
     rid.dwFlags := 0;
     rid.hwndTarget := 0; // If NULL it follows the keyboard focus
     RegisterRawInputDevices(@rid, 1, SizeOf(rid));
   end;

   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     RegisterListener;
     Application.OnMessage := OnMessage;
   end;
   ```
2. Теперь в обработчике событий можно получить "сырые" данные, из которых узнать детали ввода. Сам ввод тут лучше не брать, т.к. он не облагорожен (например, для планшета x/y координаты не спроецированы на монитор, а от 0 до 65535, также, если я верно понимаю документацию, не применены ускорения курсора и т.п.).

   ```
   procedure TForm1.OnMessage(var aMsg: TMsg; var aHandled: Boolean);
   var
     dwSize: Cardinal;
     ri: tagRAWINPUT;
   begin
     if aMsg.message = WM_INPUT then
     begin
       GetRawInputData(HRAWINPUT(aMsg.lParam), RID_INPUT, nil, dwSize, SizeOf(RAWINPUTHEADER));

       if dwSize = 0 then
         ShowMessage('Can not allocate memory');

       if GetRawInputData(HRAWINPUT(aMsg.lParam), RID_INPUT, @ri, dwSize, SizeOf(RAWINPUTHEADER)) <> dwSize then
         ShowMessage('GetRawInputData doesn''t return correct size!');

       // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinputdevicelist
       // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawmouse
       if ri.header.dwType = RIM_TYPEMOUSE then
       begin
         if ri.mouse.usFlags and $1 = 0 then
           fLastInputMode := imRelative
         else
           fLastInputMode := imAbsolute;
       end;
     end;
   end;
   ```
3. Теперь имея флаг `fLastInputMode` можно в обработчике `Panel1MouseMove` менять логику в зависимости от типа:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,Y: Integer);
   var
     origin: TPoint;
   begin
     case fLastInputMode of
       imRelative: begin
                     // Stick mouse cursor to start location, otherwise it stucks at screen border
                     origin := TControl(Sender).ClientToScreen(Point(fOriginCursorX, fOriginCursorY));
                     SetCursorPos(origin.X, origin.Y)
                   end;
       imAbsolute: begin
                     // Update tablet cursor origin, otherwise its offset will grow exponentially
                     fOriginCursorX := X;
                     fOriginCursorY := Y;
                   end;
     end;
   ```

---

Методы WinApi и описания структур данных легко найти на гитхабе, тут их не привожу. Если интересен тестовый проект - https://github.com/Kromster80/raw_input_test/